# How to Retry tasklet in Spring batch?

Tags: spring-batch

How to retry a method invoker task, I know that if a chunk task fails there is option to retry and there is option to setup backoff policies but, in method invoker task xsd I can't find retry option. Is there any other alternative to retry the task in case of failure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use spring-retry and [declarative retry](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/retry.html#declarativeRetry); just apply `<aop:config>` tag and configure interceptor.

> To change the policies or listeners, you only need to inject an
>   instance of RetryTemplate into the interceptor

Comment: Is there a way to do it when configuring jobs programmatically using the fluent JobBuilder and StepBuilder APIs?

Comment: Maybe with a FaultTolerantStepBuilder, but is just a supposition because I have never used javaconfig,sorry

Comment: I found a question for exactly this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23523130/how-to-configure-fault-tolerance-programmatically-for-a-spring-tasklet-not-a-ch

Answer (score 0):

I had a requirement to retry when I had a REST call failure to read data. The retry in spring would not retry Reader failure. The solution is basically what @Luca said using RetryTemplate and aop.

```
<bean id="retryAdvice"
    class="org.springframework.retry.interceptor.RetryOperationsInterceptor">
    <property name="retryOperations">
        <bean class="org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate">
            <property name="retryPolicy">
                <bean class="org.springframework.retry.policy.SimpleRetryPolicy">
                    <property name="maxAttempts" value="5" />
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="backOffPolicy">
                <bean class="org.springframework.retry.backoff.ExponentialBackOffPolicy">
                    <property name="initialInterval" value="3000"></property>
                    <property name="maxInterval" value="60000"></property>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut
        expression="execution(* com.mypackage.MyService.get*(..))"
        id="remoteMethodPointCut"></aop:pointcut>
    <aop:advisor pointcut-ref="remoteMethodPointCut"
        advice-ref="retryAdvice" />
</aop:config>
```